SQL syntax error (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000):) while trying to update records in python
Part of my code calls up an edit window. In this window it pulls the information from the record you want to update based of the C_ID unique ID number. You enter the ID number in the box for either updating or deleted the record.
I have written the update code a few different ways, it has been a good long while since I worked with SQL and just started to write python a week ago, and for the life of me I can't figure out the issue at hand. If you need to see more of the code I could post it. Right now every connects through a py script for connecting to DB so I don't have to type it out, or copy past it all the time. The Cursor is in that code as well, reason for the cur, conn =
def update():
            cur, conn = connection.get_connection()

            record_id = delete_box.get()

            cur.execute("""UPDATE car_exp SET 
                        C_ID =:C_ID, 
                        C_Date =:C_Date, 
                        C_Payment =:C_Payment, 
                        C_CAA =:C_CAA, 
                        C_Maintenance =:C_Maintenance, 
                        C_Insurance =:C_Insurance, 
                        C_Gas =:C_Gas, 
                        C_Addt_1 =:C_Addt_1, 
                        C_Addt_2 =:C_Addt_2 
                        
                        WHERE C_ID = :C_ID""",
                        {
                        'C_ID': record_id,
                        'Date': C_Date_editor.get (),
                        'C_Payment': C_Payment_editor.get (), 
                        'C_CAA': C_CAA_editor.get (),
                        'C_Maintenance': C_Maintenance_editor.get (),
                        'C_Gas': C_Gas_editor.get (),
                        'C_Addt_1': C_Addt_1_editor.get (),
                        'C_Addt_2': C_Addt_2_editor.get ()})

            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

I have tried this method as well for execute, same error.
("UPDATE car_exp SET C_ID=%s,C_Date=%s,C_Payment=%s,C_CAA=%s,C_Maintenance=%s,C_Insurance=%s,C_Gas=%s,C_Addt_1=%s,C_Addt_2=%s, WHERE C_ID = :C_ID",{
                        'C_ID': C_ID_editor.get(),
                        'C_Date': C_Date_editor.get (),
                        'C_Payment': C_Payment_editor.get (), 
                        'C_CAA': C_CAA_editor.get (),
                        'C_Maintenance': C_Maintenance_editor.get (),
                        'C_Gas': C_Gas_editor.get (),
                        'C_Addt_1': C_Addt_1_editor.get (),
                        'C_Addt_2': C_Addt_2_editor.get ()})

When I go to run this part of the code I get the error:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':C_ID,
C_Date =:C_Date,
C_Paym' at line 2


Remove the stray , before the WHERE. (this is in the second query the first one appears to be ok)

The error message undicates that python did not replace the placeholders with parameter values.

Thank for the info, I don't see a stray ',' before 'WHERE',
If I remove the comma after WHERE gives out a warning that it's missing.
@PaulT.

@Corpghent ... in the last query, it's here: C_Addt_2=%s, WHERE (before the WHERE)
